# Web Server (Shared VPS Windows), store file checksums en masse for cron

Tags: c#, php, windows, storage, shared-hosting

I tried looking for answers , so hopefully this is not a duplicate.

I am working on a web server, and what I need to do is maintain a checksum "database" of all files within the public_html folder. 
I can run the cron job using PHP or C# , and so I'm comfortable with this in either language.

- [Goal]:   Maintain checksum database (properly) of all files (approx. 800,000)
- [Purpose]: Monitor changes and perform heuristics on new files (security related)
- [Problem]: Speed
- [Question]:  What in your opinion or expertise is the BEST way to store that information?

Windows Hosting environment.

I have to run a loop over every file in every subdirectory, and check if the current md5(file) is identical to the stored_md5(file), and if not , queue up some tasks for later.

- If it's stored in say a mysql database, it will have to have really good indexes on the MD5 32char checksum keys, or it will be incredibly slow to process.
- If it's stored in a file, then that checksum information has to be loaded into memory, which is not a good idea for my web server.

Thoughts? Recommendations?

Comment: It sounds like perhaps the shared VPS solution isn't the best place for your software given your requisites.

Comment: "I tried looking for answers , so hopefully this is not a duplicate." Do you think this line will prevent your question from being marked as a duplicate if it is? It's probably not by the way, so good job.

Comment: And I'm starting to think the same thing @Ohgodwhy , ideally this would be split up into linux VPS units, but budget is always difficult. Am going to have ponder that point.